# How to log into a website with VBS script when the sign in button lacks an ID

Tags: authentication, vbscript

I'm trying to use a simple VBS script to log into a forum and I'm able to enter the username and password using the IDs of those field, but I'm unable to have it click sign in button.

This is all the information I can find to identify the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="ipsButton ipsButton_primary" tabindex="2" accesskey="s" role="button">Sign In</button>
```

This is my script so far:

```
set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.Open "https:/forums/index.php?/login/"
WScript.Sleep (3000)
.getElementByID("Auth").value = "username"
.getElementByID("Password").value = "password"
.getElementsByClassName("ipsButton ipsButton_primary")(0).Submit
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the "button" elements then verify it's the correct button. If so, call the click method of that button.

```
For Each b In document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    If b.accesskey = "s" And b.value = "Sign In" Then b.click
Next
```

You should be able to use *either* condtion in the `If` statement, as long as they only apply to that specific button.